# Extract Unity Gameobject coordinates and export to text file

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a level in which I have placed many instances of a prefab Gameobject (targets). I need to use the coordinates of those targets in a script. Is there a way to obtain the xyz vector coordinates of all those objects and export them to a text file? Right now I need to manually copy-past each individual target from the Unity inspector to MonoDevelop, which is a PITA...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the coordinates of an object use `item.transform.Position` where item is a reference to the object you want to get coordinates for. The result is a Vector3 from which you can do `.x`, `.y` or `.z` to get individual coordinates/

[Writing to a text file is well-documented.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287548%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Alternatively, you may want to look into [Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233843.aspx)

EDIT: To do this for all objects in the scene:

```
string filePath = "D:/mycoords.txt";
string coordinates = "";
var objects = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType(Transform) as Transform[];
foreach(Transform trans in objects)
{
    coordinates+= "x: " + trans.position.x.ToString() + ", y: " + trans.position.y.ToString() + ", z: " + trans.position.z.ToString() + System.Environment.NewLine;
}

//Write the coords to a file
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filePath,coordinates);
```

NOTE: FindObjectsOfType will *not* return any assets (meshes, textures, prefabs, ...) or inactive objects.

EDIT3: If you want to only get your Targets, add a script to you Target prefab called "SaveMeToFile" and use this code:

```
string filePath = "D:/mycoords.txt";
string coordinates = "";
var objects = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType(SaveMeToFile) as SaveMeToFile[];
foreach(SaveMeToFile smtf in objects)
{
    Transform trans = smtf.transform;
    coordinates+= "x: " + trans.position.x.ToString() + ", y: " + trans.position.y.ToString() + ", z: " + trans.position.z.ToString() + System.Environment.NewLine;
}

//Write the coords to a file
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filePath,coordinates);
```

EDIT 4: Or if you have any component specific to your target you can use that instead of SaveMeToFile in the code above, saving you from having to create a new, worthless Monobehaviour

Comment: Thanks, but that would still require a lot of manual work unfortunately. I was hoping to extract all coordinates from a list of 75+ gameobjects I placed on my scene, so I can use these in an external script.